# PHP PDO search for a value in two or more columns using one string

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I want to find a value from a row using PDO I use the following method:

```
//Search whether user exists
$sqlQueryEmailLogin = $dbh->prepare("SELECT vendor_id, first_name, last_name, email_login, user_password, passport_id, login_attempts, login_last_attempt FROM $tableVendorDetails WHERE email_login = ?");
$sqlQueryEmailLogin->bindValue(1, $emailLogin);
$sqlQueryEmailLogin->execute();
```

and the following PHP code for the search field

```
$emailLogin = 'xyz@abc.com'
```

Now I'd like to search two columns or more and use the following code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ? AND status = ?"; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $id); 
$stmt->bindValue(2, $status); 
$stmt->execute();
```

I'd like to search the two columns from a string. How should I go about it, please?

The string value i go is from a html form with one input box

I'd like a string that is capable of searching two values from a MySQL table e.g. 
`$search = $id;` and

```
$seach = $status;
```

in this case both cancel each other

Comment: ... and the problem with that 2nd example is?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just set `$id` and `$status` from the form inputs in `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: "a html form with one input box" - could you share that HTML with us?

Comment: I'd like a string that is capable of searching two values from a MySQL table e.g. $search = $id; and $seach = $status; in this case both cancel each other

Comment: Oh, you mean like `->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ? OR status = ?")` and then `->execute([$search, $search])`?

Comment: @Ja͢ck yeah I think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify it by using the method described by @gbestard. But you should also do this:

```
$search = 'asdf'; // fill this with your form input

$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id OR status = :status"; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':id'     => $search, 
    ':status' => $search,
));
```

Notice the change to `OR` in the query, and supplying the `$search` multiple times...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. I still have to try it. Why didn't you use id = ? AND status = ?. I am asking for my general knowledge

Comment: @user2333968 You could still do that... But at the companies I worked for, this notation is preferred, since it is more readable (and thus easily maintained code). I have updated the indentation to show you even more readability. Notice the comma after the last element in the array, and the better formatting by using linebreaks and indentation.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I'm using

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id AND status = :status"; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id , ':status' => $status));
```

Comment: While I agree that this style is preferable, how does it solve his problem? They're both equivalent.

Comment: This is right. It solves the problem by defining query variables with `:status` See the PHP DOCs to verify http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: @Lex Have you read that documentation? OPs snippet should work just as well with question marks and numeric indexes for the parameters. So if that doesn't work, there is no reason to think this will.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id AND status = :status";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id); 
$stmt->bindValue(':status', $status); 
$stmt->execute();
```

See docs http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OR` instead of `AND`. That way, you will get all rows that match either by id or by status.

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ? OR status = ?
```